# How to import nano (couchdb) - typescript

Tags: typescript, couchdb, node-modules, couchdb-nano

I have trouble importing and using nano in my node application.

The js way (from the doc) is :

```
var nano = require('nano')('http://localhost:5984');
```

How do I do that with typescript ?

I tried

```
import * as Nano from "nano";
let nano = new Nano('http://localhost:5984');
```

But then I get : Nano is not an object.

Answer (score 3):

By installing @types/nano we can look at :

```
node_modules/@types/nano/index.d.ts
```

where we see the lines :

```
declare function nano(config: nano.Configuration | string):
 nano.ServerScope | nano.DocumentScope;
```

Meaning Nano is a function not an object, so the answer :

```
import * as Nano from "nano";
let nano = Nano('http://localhost:5984');
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to typecast that like below:

```
import * as Nano from "nano";

let nano: Nano.ServerScope = <Nano.ServerScope>Nano('http://localhost:5984');
let db = nano.use(database);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since version 7.x nano has built-in TS type information for IDEs, and there's no need import additional typings.

Following should be enough:

```
import Nano from "nano";
let n = Nano('localhost:5984');
```