# Import CouchDB Nano 6.4 Typings in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, couchdb, typescript-typings, couchdb-nano

I want to use CouchDB as database-backend in a NodeJS app with Typescript. [CouchDb-Nano](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-nano) is used for this, since it provides the required Typings. So I installed both packages:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/nano": "^6.4.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "nano": "^6.4.3"
  }
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46061756/9428314) for the correct TS import syntax. It doesn't work for me. By playing around, I found the following compiling:

```
import Nano from "nano";
let nano = Nano("http://localhost:5984");
```

But my intellisens in VS code seems totally different. For example, the docs say that nano has a attribute called `db` which several methods like this for selecting a database:

`var alice = nano.db.use('alice');`

This code gave me a error, that no attribute called `db`exists. Intellisense show me only `auth, config, session` as attributes:

[VS Code intellisense screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9y74u.png)

According to the [comment-header](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/nano/index.d.ts), the typings are for couchdb-nano (no other project which is called nano, too) and also for version 6.4, which is used here.

So what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you should be able to cast the Nano function to the ServerScope interface and then intellisense should work when interacting with your nano object.

```js
import Nano, { ServerScope } from "nano";

const nano = Nano("http://localhost:5984") as ServerScope;
const alice = nano.db.use("alice");
```

Comment: Look twice before you get stuck on this example above. It was very helpful too but the answers below were much better since they separate `instance` and `database`.

Answer (score 1):

Found out that this issue is caused by an ambiguous return value in the type defintion:

```
declare function nano(
  config: nano.Configuration | string
): nano.ServerScope | nano.DocumentScope<any>;
```

The `nano` function can have `nano.ServerScope` or `nano.DocumentScope<any>` as return value. By doing some reverse engineering, I learned that `ServerScope` is the right class for me. It provides properties like `db`, which are present in the documentation.

So we need to explicitly cast here:

```
let nanoInstance = <Nano.ServerScope>Nano("http://localhost:5984");
```

Now all the example-codes from the docs works well like this:

```
nanoInstance.db.create("test123");
```

#### What's the difference?

I'm too new in nosql-databases for exactly explaining the difference. But i'd assume that by providing some kind of url-parameter, we can directly connect to a single document, instead of the entire database. I'll try to edit this post when I know more. For the moment, this is not primary relevant for me.

Comment: `nano.db.create('test123');` would create a database named `test123` and this statement: `const db = nano.db.use('test123');` will use the `test123` database as `db`. Then you can do lots of things to the `test123` database like `db.multipart.insert(...)` and many more. Take a look at [this documentation](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-nano).

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using nano with typescript, and intellisense seems to be working fine. I had it setup this way.

```
import Nano from 'nano';

const instance: Nano.ServerScope = Nano('http://localhost:5984/');
const db: Nano.DocumentScope<{}> = instance.db.use('alice');
```

For the dependencies, I'm using:

```
"dependencies": {
  "nano": "^7.0.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/nano": "^6.4.6"
}
```